# Indicator for "sending keyboard input to all splits" in byobu

Tags: tmux, byobu

Is there a way to present current `tmux` options in the status bar?
More specifically, is there a way to indicate whether the `synchronize-panes` option is set, and the keyboard input is sent to all "splits"?